# MSAL Angular redirect to "/#code=..." after login popup or redirect with msalGuard

Tags: angular, msal-angular

I try to use MSAL 2.5.8 in my Angular 11 project but after login using canActivate: [MsalGuard], it redirect the popup to "http://localhost:4200/#code=0.AX..."

[I followed this github to implement msal into my project](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/msal-lts/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-sample-app)

app.module.ts

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: '...', 
      authority: '...', 
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
    },
    system: {
      allowNativeBroker: false, // Disables WAM Broker
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    }
  });
}
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']);
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}
export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: ['user.read']
    },
    loginFailedRoute: '/login-failed'
  };
}
...
 providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },,
    TacheService,
    CookieService,
    { provide: REDUCER_TOKEN, useFactory: getReducers },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true },
    MatNativeDateModule,
    EnvServiceProvider,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent], // MsalRedirectComponent bootstrapped here
})
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  title = '';
  isIframe = false;
  loginDisplay = false;
  private readonly _destroying$ = new Subject<void>();
  activeAccount: AccountInfo | null = null;



  constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    private oauthService: OAuthService,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: MsalService,
    private msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService,
    @Inject(MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG) private msalGuardConfig: MsalGuardConfiguration,
    private location: Location
    
  ) {}
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const currentPath = this.location.path();
    this.isIframe = BrowserUtils.isInIframe() && !window.opener && currentPath.indexOf("logout") < 0; 
    this.setLoginDisplay();
    
    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.setLoginDisplay();
        this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
      })
  }
  checkAndSetActiveAccount(){
  
    let activeAccount = this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount();

    if (!activeAccount && this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
      let accounts = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts();
      this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
    }
  }
  setLoginDisplay() {
    this.loginDisplay = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
  }

  loginRedirect() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
      this.authService.loginRedirect({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest} as RedirectRequest);
    } else {
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    }
  }

  loginPopup() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
      this.authService.loginPopup({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest} as PopupRequest)
        .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
        });
      } else {
        this.authService.loginPopup()
          .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
            this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
      });
    }
  }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: 'profile',
  component: ProfileComponent,
  canActivate: [MsalGuard]
}, 
{   // Needed for hash routing
path: 'error',
component: HomeComponent
},
{
// Needed for hash routing
path: 'state',
component: HomeComponent
},
{
// Needed for hash routing
path: 'code',
component: HomeComponent
},
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: [MsalGuard]
},

];
const initialNavigation = (!BrowserUtils.isInIframe() && !BrowserUtils.isInPopup()) || window.location.href.indexOf("logout") > 0; // Remove this line to use Angular Universal


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    useHash: true,
    // Don't perform initial navigation in iframes or popups, except for logout
    initialNavigation: initialNavigation ? 'enabled' : 'disabled' // Remove this line to use Angular Universal
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

[Result in the popup after trying to go to https://localhost:4200/#/profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKnRv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a placeholder route named `code` to your `app-routing.module.ts`. That's the **expected result** when you are using hash routing in Angular. E.g.:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    // some other routes
    {
        // Needed for hash routing
        path: 'code',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
]
```

Make sure that this route is not protected by `MsalGuard`.

From [official documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/msal-guard.md#using-the-msal-guard-with-hash-routing):

> When using the `HashLocationStrategy` with your Angular app, we strongly recommend setting placeholder routes (such as `/code`) in your `app-routing.module.ts` to prevent triggering the Angular router when AAD returns the auth code response in the hash, as you may experience issues completing authentication without doing so.

Also,

> These placeholder routes **should not be protected by the `MsalGuard`**, and should not point to a component that triggers interaction or makes protected API calls on page load.

These examples ([1](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/070f3435954cb264a55b012adae788f8eab8d46b/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-sample-app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts#L32), [2](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/070f3435954cb264a55b012adae788f8eab8d46b/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-b2c-sample/src/app/app-routing.module.ts#L27)) and [this comment](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/3292#issuecomment-806255566) from GitHub states that you need to define a placeholder route for `code` in `app-routing.module.ts`